# How can I iterate through nested HTML lists without returning the "youngest" children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, loops

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zayjeLrk/12/

I want to iterate through an HTML nested list that is *3-layers* deep.

```
<ul>
    <li>animals
        <ul>
            <li>birds
                <ul>
                    <li>crow</li>
                    <li>parrot</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>reptiles</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>plants</li>
    <li>bugs</li>
</ul>
```

I want it to iterate through the list so that it returns the elements in this order (note, this isn't exact text that will be displayed in fiddle; the fiddle will also include sub-elements):

**animals, birds, reptiles, plants, bugs**

Meaning, it skips the "youngest" or "deepest" children. As of now, I am iterating through a jQuery object.

```
var stepList = $("ul  li ul li > ul li");
```

This obviously gets the children **crow, parrot** which is what I don't want. I need something that returns something like below *minus* those 2 elements:

```
var stepList = $("ul li");
```

**QUESTION:** Is there a jQuery object I can assign to `stepList` with that will give me everything *EXCEPT* the children?

Edit: If not, how can I get achieve my goal?

Comment: Well, this might involve a little bit of `.filter()` code, rather than a pure selector. For this to work, it first has to know just how many levels is the deepest. If "crow" became a 'container heading' with "African Crow", "Western Black Crow", then suddenly "parrot" would be valid, right?

Comment: have you tried `$("ul li:not(:last-child)");`

Comment: @Katana314 at this point it is only 3 layers, but there may be some point in the future where that could change (either 2 layers or maybe up to 4), so it would be nice to know of a "filter" solution like you said

Comment: You should set some classes regarding specific LI nested level while generating HTML markup in first place.

Comment: agree with Mr Wolf.  I would use a `class="skip"` marker on things i didn't want, and then use a generic `li:not('.skip')`

Comment: What is the actual algorithm?  Down to 2nd level.  Down N levels, but just not lowest level (if so, what happens when the lowest level is a different level in different branches)?  It is NOT clear what the general algorithm is here at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are thinking too "robustly" for my purposes. I don't need to check all those conditions. The loop I used to display the contents in the fiddle is actually what I need to use in my actual program (essentially)

Comment: So, are you just saying the two levels down of children is what you want?  I can't offer a good, general purpose answer without knowing the rules.  And, sorry, but I like to offer the most robust answers which are more general purpose and don't hard code to one specific situation as I think they are more useful for all.  If you don't want to answer my question, then I'll just move on as you appear to have plenty of hard coded answers to choose from.

Comment: By "youngest" children I presume you mean leaf nodes. https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Tree_(data_structure)#Terminologies_used_in_Trees

Comment: ^ that, from the examples it seems the most deeply nested elements are the only ones to be excluded, and I believe I solved that half an hour ago ?

Comment: Yes, if you're looking for "animals, birds, reptiles, plants, bugs" then you're looking for *nodes* whose *depths* are less than the *height of the tree*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just check the nesting level by counting parents

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).parents('ul').length < 3 ) {

        // do stuff

    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zayjeLrk/14/)

To make it more dynamic one could simply find the deepest nesting level and filter based on that

```
var lis   = $("ul li");

var nest  = $.map(lis, function(item) {
    return $(item).parents('ul').length;
});

var max   = Math.max.apply(null, nest);

var stepList = lis.filter(function(index, item) {
    return $(item).parents('ul').length !== max;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zayjeLrk/15/)

Comment: This seems like a pretty hard coded solution and not a general solution at all.  Maybe works for one unique case, but unlikely the best general purpose answer.  For example, what if the hierarchy varies in depth in different branches?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about solving this problem is getting *all* children (like you are right now), then iterating through them and cutting out the children with no children of the same element.

So get all children like you did.

```
var stepList = $("ul  li ul li > ul li");
```

Then:

```
var el = "li";
var listWithoutYoungestChildren = [];
for(var i = 0; i < stepList.length; i++) {
     if($(stepList[i]).children(el).length > 0) 
         listWithoutYoungestChildren.push(stepList[i]);
}
```